# Does ScrollableNavigationBar support dynamic Styling?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set the colour of the header title of the ScrollableNavigationBar dynamically based on theme but it changes only when I refresh the screen (forced rendering) .In case of a simple text it does not give any error in changing the colour based on theme.
import ScrollableNavigationBar, {
BackButton,
NavigationBar,
StatusBarComponent,
} from "react-native-scrollable-navigation-bar";
<ScrollableNavigationBar
rightIcons={[
<AccountHeader navigation={navigation} style={{ top: 50 }} />,
]}
transitionPoint={155}
headerHeight={Platform.OS === "android" ? 155 : 165}
navigationBarHeight={100}
title={${message}}

```
       headerTitleStyle={{
       color: theme === "light" ? "#000000" : "#ffffff",
       fontFamily: "Century-Gothic",
       paddingLeft: -2,
       fontSize: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 30 : getFontSize(30),
       }}
       headerBackgroundColor={headerBackgroundColor}
  />
```

Any suggestion would be welcome, why its happening ?
I have no clue how to address this issue